# T410 Memory upgrade Mixing Size&Clock

Tags: configuration, memory, dell

We have a Dell T410 server using :

- A4/B4 -
- A1/A1 - 2GB/2GB 1066mhz
- A2/A2 - 2GB/2GB 1066mhz
- A3/A3 -

I have 2x4GB 1333mkz for upgrade to 16GB.

But :

- A4/B4 -
- A1/A1 - 2GB/2GB 1066mhz
- A2/A2 - 2GB/2GB 1066mhz
- A3/A3 - 4GB/4GB 1333mhz

and

- A4/B4 - 2GB/2GB 1066mhz
- A1/A1 - 2GB/2GB 1066mhz
- A2/A2 - 4GB/4GB 1333mhz
- A3/A3 -

Won't work :'(
warning "memory configuration".

Comment: Did you use registered ECC or unregistered/unbuffered EEC RAM? (For both old and new modules)?

Answer (score 2):

The T410 uses a dual docket motherboard with LGA 1366 triple channel CPU's.

If you only have **one CPU installed** then:

- you only can use the DIMMs sockets connected to that CPU.
- Best performance will be with 3 DIMMs installed since the CPU supports triple channel access.
- All DIMMs must be of the same type:
  All DIMMS used at the same speed. (In your case 533 MHz for the  -1066 modules)
  All DIMMs must be registered or unregistered.
  All DIMMS must use ECC. (See manual page 33). Regular non-ECC modules are not supported.

[image: T410 manual]

If you have **two CPUs installed** then both have their own (local) memory.

You will need to install them in a very specific order, as show in this part of the manual:
[image]

Most of the rules which applied to the single CPU setup also apply here, though you might get away with running the -1333 modules at -1066 speeds.

Also note that if you enabled memory mirroring then you must have identical memory configuration in Channel_0 and Channel_1 and not have memory in Channel_3.

Comment: Graphics! In color! They aren't kittens, but +1 nonetheless.

Comment: I considered just copying the text, but I figured out this would be a mild hint to get someone read the manual. Which is always a good thing before ordering server parts.

Answer (score 1):

Look at page 34 of the [T410 technical guide](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/server-poweredge-t410-technical-guide-book_1.pdf). You can only install 3 DIMM's if you have 1 processor. If you have 2 processors, you must install in pairs as shown in the table. Also, your DIMM speeds must match; you can not mix speeds.